# Java: Why is BorderLayout calling setSize() followed by setBounds()?

Tags: java, layout-manager

I'm trying to get my head around proper use of the different LayoutManagers to make my GUI design skills more efficient and effective by gaining a detailed understanding of what is going on under the hood. I am looking at the source for BorderLayout, and in the code snippet below taken from the layoutContainer() method, I note calls to the child Component's setSize() method followed by setBounds(). Looking at the source for these methods of Component, setSize() actually calls setBounds() with the current values for Component.x and Component.y. Why is this done (and not entirely redudant)? Doesn't the setBounds() call completely overwrite the results of the setSize() call?

```
if ((c=getChild(NORTH,ltr)) != null) {
    c.setSize(right - left, c.height);
    Dimension d = c.getPreferredSize();
    c.setBounds(left, top, right - left, d.height);
    top += d.height + vgap;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some components, when calculating their preferred size, will take their current size into account. So, for example, a text area doesn't really know how high it wants to be until it knows how wide it is; then it can work out its text wrapping and figure out how many lines it needs.

So here, the call to `setSize()` is really just specifying the width. Then the layout manager gets and sets the height preferred *for that width*.

Comment: Amazing! That makes perfect sense. It is going to take me a long time to fully understand all the details of what is going on beneath the "normal" interfaces. Thanks.